# An infinite quantity divided up into infinite number of boxes?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm not sure how to phrase this in a proper set theory setting but let's say that one has a quantity which is infinitely large and then divides the quantity up so that it goes into a collection of boxes, in the limit as the number of boxes goes to infinity, does that mean the amount of the quantity in each box will get infinitely small?

So the question is like, what happens with the two infinities when you have an infinite amount of something being divided up into an infinite number of boxes?

Comment: The best way to model this kind of behaviour from what I can understand is a partition. But the cardinals involved will depend on how the partition is defined and the size of the set you started with.

Comment: Let's say the quantity was only extremely large, rather than infinitely large.  If the quantity were portioned out into boxes, in the limit of infinitely many boxes in that case would the amount in each box become infinitely small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the amount of stuff in each box can stay the same, or even get larger. Here is a simple example: suppose we want to distribute countably many balls into countably many boxes.

We can do it by putting one ball in each box, sequentially; here the number of balls in each box is either $0$ or $1$, and never decreases.

We can also do it as follows: first place a ball in box $1$. Then place balls in boxes $1$ and $2$. Then place balls in boxes $1, 2, 3$. Then place balls in boxes $1, 2, 3, 4$. And so on. At the $n^{th}$ step of this process the count of balls in boxes looks like

$$n, n-1, n-2, n-3, \dots, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, \dots $$

and in particular the number of balls in each box is increasing. In the limit $n \to \infty$ every box has countably many balls in it.

Comment: This argument shows among other things that "division" of infinities by infinities doesn't have a unique answer in general. Loosely speaking, "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" could be either finite or infinite.